# What is the Use of monotonically_increasing_id in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to understand the use of monotonically_increasing_id in Spark SQL.

Can anyone explain with an example, why do we need to have monotonically increasing ids  in case of dataframes?

Comment: It's semantically equivalent to a AUTOINCREMENT key in a RDBMS table

Comment: @cricket_007 It's not quite the same because it does not generate a consecutive sequence of numbers.

Comment: @TerryDactyl If you delete ID's post-creation of an RDBMS's incremented value, then they are also not always consecutive, but the value is still always increasing. I get your point though.